# Сленгове значення слова "dig"

Tags: переклад

Слово **dig** в англійській мові набуло сленгового значення "бути у захваті, подобатися", наприклад:

> I dig your new style.

Мені необхідно зберегти сленг, оскільки це фраза із діалогу підлітків. Чи буде використання слова **кайфувати** коректним у перекладі? Фраза "Мені подобається твій новий стиль" у цьому контексті звучатиме сухо і неемоційно.

Comment: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3289/240 ми подумали, що це можна було б і не видаляти, бо то два різних слова, а не просто питання про форму.

Comment: Є ще «[тащитися](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53410/376003.html)».

Answer (score 1):

В Інтернеті можна знайти [статтю](https://conferences.vntu.edu.ua/index.php/all-hum/all-hum-2018/paper/viewFile/5464/4586), де і дається відповідь на Ваше запитання. Цитую:

> Hey,  I  **dig**  your  new  style.  Where  did  you  buy  that  T-shirt?    Молодіжний  сленг  у  цьому  реченні представлений  словом  DIG- у  точному  перекладі - «копати»,  але  на  сучасному  неформальному жаргоні - «**ловити кайф**», «**тягнутися**»; так говорять про те, що дійсно подобається.

Також бачимо переклад цього слова на сучасний молодіжний сленг [тут](http://linguist.lviv.ua/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF-20-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/) (в прямому перекладі «копати», але в сленговому значенні «ловити кайф», «балдіти»).

Зауважу, що це варіанти перекладу цього слова саме для діалогу між підлітками.